# Why do I get a 403 error while accessing a wap django application with csrf middleware enabled?

Tags: django, csrf, wap

Any ideas? When accessing from desktop browser it's all ok.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps your WAP browser does not [support cookies](http://www.thewirelessfaq.com/are_cookies_supported_in_the_wap_environment)?  [Cookies are required](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#how-it-works) for CSRF middleware to work.  If you intend to primarily target browsers like that, you might consider either using [@csrf_exempt](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#exceptions) for WAP-accessible views or disabling the middleware.